# call a image and a link from the servlet

Tags: java, servlets

With this code i am able to render a image from a servlet ,But my business says.I need to add a link say"www.google.com".If i click this image.Is there any way that i can access a image with the link on.I need to flush it directly from the servlet should not use jsp.Can any one please help me out.

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        String filename = sc.getRealPath("image.JPG");

        resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        // Set content size
        File file = new File(filename);
        resp.setContentLength((int)file.length());

        // Open the file and output streams
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);

        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request , response);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you want to add a link say google.com and on click of it shows a image.

Firstly you don't need to send image as a response rather you need to anchor link and add javascript function onclick on that link.

```
out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
                                        "Transitional//EN\">\n" +
                "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD><TITLE>Hello WWW</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY>\n" +
                "<a href='www.google.com'><img src='imagePath' /></a>\n" +
                "</BODY></HTML>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an `<a>` element around the `<img>` element in the markup.

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="imageServlet" />
</a>
```

---

By the way, the `sc.getRealPath()` suggests that your image file is *already* in public webcontent folder. Why not just using `<img src="image.JPG">` instead? Or is the servlet heavily oversimplified?

Comment: Problem is - their servlet is returning an image, not markup. If this to stay as-is, then the answer is "no" you can't return an image with a link. Just to make sure @user1046671 understands.

It could be a job for another servlet to return markup, or this servlet has to be modified to return text/html like in your example.

Comment: @balusc:what maksimov is saying is exactly right we are returning a image not a mark up.So is there no way turn around that we can get both the image and thelink.My task is to render a image and if clicked on the image it should pop up the site provided.

Comment: @maksimov:if i change it to text or html will my image work as.To get the image we need to have image/jpeg.

Comment: @user1046671: in other words, you don't have control over the markup on the web page which is using the imageservlet in the `<img>` element? Well, then it's end of story. You'd need to look for an alternate approach. E.g. `<script src="imageServletScript"></script>` and then letting the JS code populate the `<a><img>` dynamically.

Comment: @user1046671 in basic terms, getting a link (a markup) and an image - are two different request/response pairs. So you can't return both in one servlet call. If you web container is able to return static resources like images, you can modify your servlet to return markup with the link and an <img> tag to your static image. If not - you need to implement both markup and image handling via your servlet(s).

Comment: @maksimov:As stated by you in your above comment "If you web container is able to return static resources like images, you can modify your servlet to return markup with the link and an <img> tag to your static image".What changes in my above servlet will do it?

Comment: @user1046671 please refer to answer provided by Quoi above. Don't forget to change the returned content type to "text/html" as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood correct you can return html with link on image:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="yourImageRenderingServletPath"></a>
```

So you will have one servlet that render html and second that render image. To prevent image buffering in browser you can add random param id = (new Random()).nextInt():

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="yourImageRenderingServletPath?id=124"></a>
```